# How to prefix all JSON responses in play2 to prevent JSONP escalation via vulnerable requests

Tags: json, security, playframework-2.0, prefix

I want to prefix all my JSON responses with a sequence of quotes like ")]}',\n", to prevent JSONP escalation vulnerabilities.

How it can be done in play2 framework ?
I've set my bodyparsers to JSON and prefixed all responses manually, but i'm searching for a more elegant way to do this job via native framework features.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What do you mean by "JSONP escalation vulnerabilities"? ([googling for it](https://www.google.com/search?q=JSONP+escalation+vulnerabilities) returns this very question as a first result and pretty much nothing else).

Do you want to prevent people from using your JSON as JSONP? Then just don't include the [JSONP padding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP#Padding).

Do you want to prevent people from using your JSON in other programs without the same origin policy issues, outside of the browser or proxy it with their own servers to serve to clients in their own domain etc.? Then it is impossible. Even if you serve some crippled JSON they will figure it out anyway. The only thing you can do is write terms and conditions that prohibit this and sue them (good luck with that).

Comment: Sorry, I've figured out my own missunderstanding of JSONP topic.
I need to prefix requests, not responses, and jackson does it just fine.

Thanks for answer.

Answer (score 1):

I think the ideal thing to do in this case is to resolve to a custom implicit play.api.http.Writable. You can do this by adding an implicit definition to a trait that your controller extends:

```
import play.api.http.Writeable

trait SecuredJsonController {
  implicit def writeableOf_JsValue(implicit codec: Codec): Writeable[JsValue] = {
    Writeable(jsval => codec.encode(")]}',\n" + jsval.toString))
  }
}
```

This works well for me. I'm not sure what you meant in your reply to Zed, but it's very common to try and crash JSON vulnerability exploits by padding your response bodies just as you had originally asked. Google does it with "while(1);" and facebook with "for(;;);" so it's a good safeguard. You can see more details about such vulnerabilities [here](http://haacked.com/archive/2008/11/20/anatomy-of-a-subtle-json-vulnerability.aspx).